# Is there an R function to compute turnover and nestedness components of Hill beta diversity?

Tags: r

Just wondering if such a function exists or it may be a statistical non-sense?
If so, it would be great to have an explanation on why it is not possible.

I am aware of the 'hillR' package and the functions 'hill_taxa_parti', 'hill_func_parti', 'hill_phylo_parti' which allow to compute hill beta diversity but not the turnover and nestedness components.